# What is the difference between django.views.generic.list.ListView and django.views.generic.ListView in Django?

Tags: python, django

In [the fourth part of the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/), it used the `django.views.generic.ListView`, but in [Class-based views API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/), the `ListView` is in `django.views.generic.list.ListView`. What is the difference between `django.views.generic.list.ListView` and `django.views.generic.ListView`?

Comment: They are exactly the same, as in both names reference the same class.

Comment: so weird that place the same class under different modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are exactly referencing same class.You can check it by

```
import inspect
from django.views.generic import ListView
print(inspect.getfile(ListView))
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
print(inspect.getfile(ListView))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ListView` class actually lives in `django/views/generic/list.py`. But this is the source code of `django/views/generic/__init__.py`:

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView, TemplateView, View
from django.views.generic.dates import (
    ArchiveIndexView, DateDetailView, DayArchiveView, MonthArchiveView,
    TodayArchiveView, WeekArchiveView, YearArchiveView,
)
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import (
    CreateView, DeleteView, FormView, UpdateView,
)
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

__all__ = [
    'View', 'TemplateView', 'RedirectView', 'ArchiveIndexView',
    'YearArchiveView', 'MonthArchiveView', 'WeekArchiveView', 'DayArchiveView',
    'TodayArchiveView', 'DateDetailView', 'DetailView', 'FormView',
    'CreateView', 'UpdateView', 'DeleteView', 'ListView', 'GenericViewError',
]


class GenericViewError(Exception):
    """A problem in a generic view."""
    pass
```

As you can see it imports all of the generic views from their respective modules. This is just a convenience which allows you to import any or all of the classes from `django.views.generic` without referencing the individual modules.